How do I recognize duplicate braces and output the value? (StringDecoder(about stack))
string decodeString(const string& encoded) {
    string decoded;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < encoded.length()) {
        if (isHexDigit(encoded[i])) {
            int repeatCount = stoi(string(1, encoded[i]), nullptr, 16);
            i++;
            if (encoded[i] == '{') {
                i++;
                string subString;
                while (i < encoded.length() && encoded[i] != '}') {
                    subString += encoded[i];
                    i++;
                }
                if (i == encoded.length() || encoded[i] != '}') {
                    throw InvalidInputException();
                }
                i++;
                for (int j = 0; j < repeatCount; j++) {
                    decoded += subString;
                }
            } else {
                throw InvalidInputException();
            }
        } else {
            decoded += encoded[i];
            i++;
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}

This function decodes a given encoded string.
The format of the encoded string involves hexadecimal digits that represent the number of repetitions of a substring inside {}.
Example: "3{ABC}" would become "ABCABCABC".
If the format is incorrect (e.g., missing {}), it throws an InvalidInputException.
In this code, I'm trying to decode encoded strings. Most of them are successful, but overlapping     binarization is not recognized. For example, if I set the input '8{t}6{c}4{L}' then output is 'ttttttttccccccLLLL', if the input is 'ST4{4{3@9}}', then output is 'ST3@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@93@9'

A typical design for matching parens, braces and square brackets is to use a counter.  Encountering the open character increments the counter.  Encountering the "close" character decrements the counter.  At the "end" of the parsing, all counter variables must be zero, or there is a mismatch.

I think the problem is how your code handles this input with nested braces right 'ST4{4{3@9}}'? Usually "nesting" like that is a hint that a recursive function, or a stack data structure is the best way to solve it. I'm guessing that you're a student -- have you encountered either stacks or recursion yet so far?

Thank you for your response. I'm learning the stack right now, but I'm struggling with how to handle it if it's duplicated...I'm in a hurry because I have to submit my assignment soon... Haha
